# Unable to access the value against a specific key that has a special character

Tags: json, jq

I was trying to extract relevant data from a given JSON file. The JSON has the following format.

```
[
  {
    "partyResponse" : {
      "ns2:Address1" : "10 test Way",
      "ns2:Address2" : null,
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
]
```

I'm trying to get the value for Address1 but the following just prints out the whole JSON in an odd manner.

```
jq .[].partyResponse["ns2:Address1"] random_file_20180220.json
```

I'm trying to access it like this because the key name has a colon.

I just want to list out the address as follows.

```
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
...
```

Comment: `:` is a colon; `;` is a semicolon.

Comment: @chepner That was embarrassing... Thanks for pointing it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The shell strips the quotes. So, it is good practice to put the expression within single-quotes.

```
jq '.[].partyResponse["ns2:Address1"]' random_file_20180220.json
```

The above gives the desired result.

```
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
"10 test Way"
"3030 test Freeway"
"3030 test Freeway"
```

This only works on Linux systems though (I'm using Ubuntu).